# My voice may vary in tones. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I call for those you cannot see,
>
> To come forward in response,
>
> My voice may vary in tones,
>
> Depending on where I am.
>
> There are two ways to get the response you need,
>
> Use me or you may beat my friend instead.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it a

> Doorbell

I call for those you cannot see,

> People on the other side of the door, certainly you cannot see

To come forward in response,

> Ask them to open the door

My voice may vary in tones,

Depending on where I am.

> A doorbell comes in various tones
>  EDIT(thanks to gla3dr) : might refer to the fact that a lot of times, front and back ones sound different so that you know which one it is.

There are two ways to get the response you need,

Use me or you may beat my friend instead.

> The friend here is the door that is besides it.

Comment: *My voice may vary in tones, Depending on where I am.* might refer to the fact that a lot of times, front and back ones sound different so that you know which one it is.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> DTMF tone dialer

I call for those you cannot see,

> People on the other end of the phone, certainly you cannot see

To come forward in response,

> Ask them to come to the phone

My voice may vary in tones,

Depending on where I am.

> A DTMF tone dialer generates many tones

There are two ways to get the response you need,

Use me or you may beat my friend instead.

> The friend here is the dialpad that is also accessible.